# RecyclerView containing CardView containing GridView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a RecyclerView that contains a custom adapter/CardView. That part is working perfectly. What I'm trying to do is dynamically populate a GridView inside of the CardView but I have no idea how to do this. Is it possible?

Comment: Since recyclerview holds the same types (structures of data), are you implying that you want to actually show a gridview inside each recyclerview item?

Comment: Yes each recyclerview item should have its own individual gridview. Is that possible?

Comment: I believe it is possible but then the gridview inside the recyclerview will imply that you have to populate different data for each recyclerview item?